# Glassfish initialising Singleton bean twice

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, singleton, glassfish, ejb-3.1

I have a singleton ejb which is getting initialised twice. I have no idea why and it is completly defenting the point in having a singleton bean as far as I can tell. Any help will be appreciated. As you can see I tried to put a static boolean in to prevent the multiple initialisation (not that it should be required) but it made no difference.

Bean:

```
@Singleton 
@Startup
public class DataModelBean implements DataModelBeanLocal {

   private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(DataModelBean.class.getName());

   @PostConstruct
   public void init(){
      log.info(this);           
   }
}
```

Log output snippet:

```
2010-02-17 16:06:13,670 INFO  [AutoDeployer        :DataModelBean       ] com.xxx.xxx.datamodel.DataModelBean@117843d
2010-02-17 16:06:14,233 INFO  [AutoDeployer        :DataModelBean       ] com.xxx.xxx.datamodel.DataModelBean@62b9d3
```

Is it creating 2 beans!! or is it deploying the app twice?

As an aside I am using glassfish v3, is this mature enough? Should I use v2 or something else? Thoughts?

Comment: AFAIK, `@Singleton` is a new feature of EJB 3.1 so GFv2 is not an option.

Comment: Agreed, and I would rather stay with v3 but I need to get through issues like this.

Comment: I'm testing this (I would be extremely surprised by a big bug like this).

Comment: Likewise, just keen to know what I am doing wrong. If it works for you could you possible post your project so I can see how it differs from mine.

Comment: What other output do you see in the log file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following singleton:

```
@Singleton
public class MasterDataCache 
{
    private final static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MasterDataCache.class);

    private Map cache;

    @PostConstruct
    public void initCache() {
        logger.debug("initCache()");
        this.cache = new HashMap();
    }

    public Object get(String key){
        return this.cache.get(key);
    }

    public void store(String key,Object value){
        this.cache.put(key, value);
    }
}
```

And the following servlet:

```
@WebServlet(name="SingletonTester", urlPatterns={"/SingletonTester"})
public class SingletonTester extends HttpServlet {

    @EJB
    MasterDataCache masterDataCache;

    @Override
    public void init(){
     masterDataCache.store("startup", new Date());
    }

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        try {
            out.println("Startup time: " + masterDataCache.get("startup") );
        } finally {
            out.close();
        }
    }
}
```

packaged as a war works as expected when deployed "manually" under GFv3. It also deploys fine and works as expected under NetBeans (the `initCache` is called once only). <strike>My only problem is that the deployment fails under Eclipse (GFv3 complains about `eclipseApps/$projectName` not containing any EJB module, which are however in `eclipseApps/$projectName/WEB-INF/classses`). Sadly, this seems to be a bug with the GlassFish Eclipse plugin (at least the version I'm using). I don't see many issues in the issue tracker though... weird because this looks like a big blocking one.</strike> But outside Eclipse, GFv3 behaves normally, I couldn't reproduce your issue.

**Update:** I finally got things working under Eclipse and GlassFish v3. I won't give all the details but the problem is that I somehow failed to get my project directly recognized as a "Dynamic Web Module" 2.5, the version was initially set to 2.3 and I think this had something to do with the deployment error on GFv3. After settings up my project correctly (with a facet set to 2.5), deploying it worked fine. So I just screwed up myself.

Comment: @vkraemer I was wrong, classes are copied in `eclipseApps/$projectName/WEB-INF/classses` but glassfish complains with the following exception: `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load EJB module.  DeploymentContext does not contain any EJB  Check archive to ensure correct packaging for /home/pascal/opt/glassfishv3/glassfish/domains/domain1/eclipseApps/maven-ejb31-testcase`. But as I said, my classes are there. Regarding the version, it seems I'm using com.sun.enterprise.jst.server.sunappsrv (1.0.40).

Comment: @vkraemer Actually, the GlassFish Eclipse plugin does work fine. Maybe it could give more meaningful information but I got things working after making my application recognized as a 2.5 dynamic web module.

Comment: Using Glassfish 3.1.2 with eclipse Indigo I also have the same problem. All beans are being registered twice and `@Singleton` beans are created twice (on rebuild). Starting domain via glassfish console shows correct behavior (also on initializing clean deploy). On redeploy I also often have to clear content of glassfish folders: `eclipseApps, generated, osgi-cache\felix`.

Answer (score 1):

This issue happens when in ejb-jar.xml EJB name not equals EJB class name.

For example:

```
<ejb-name>MySingletonBean</ejb-name>
<ejb-class>ru.rozge.MyTestSingletonBean</ejb-class>
```

In this case GF registers two beans with different JNDI names ("java:global/MySingletonBean" and "java:global/MyTestSingletonBean"). And then in initialization it create two objects, first - MySingletonBean and second - MyTestSingletonBean.
Also if you use @Resource annotation for injection resources, GF actions:
1) GF creates first object "MySingletonBean" and correctly injected resources in it;
2) GF creates second object "MyTestSingletonBean" and fails on injecting (all injected resources equals null or default values).
Tested on GF 3.1 build 12 with @Singleton @Startup combo.